# Can you embed Tumblr code into a custom Tumblr page and how?

Tags: tumblr

In the Tumblr customization section, you can add new pages to your blog. This gives you a few fields, including an html editor to add the content for that custom page.

Is it possible to embed Tumblr code into that? And if so, how?

I have tried adding it to the html editor - did not work. I tried pasting the tumblr code into the html source code - that did not work either. As far as I can determine, the tumblr code does not seem to be getting parsed.

I have had no luck on google with this either. So can it be done? And if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Not as far as I know. It'll just be render as text. What are you trying to accomplish that you think you need to go this route?

Comment: @graygilmore: I want to create a contents page for our article pages. So the idea would be to loop through all pages and output the links, like we do in the theme when we output the pages in our menu.

Comment: Woops, I had a whole comment here and I think I forgot to actually add it. It went something like this: No, you won't be able use Tumblr tags on a page to accomplish this. Tumblr's template tags can only be used in the theme itself. What you might be able to do is build out the pages with JS as an object and then when you're on your Table of Contents page run a function to add the list to the DOM.

Comment: @graygilmore: Yeah, I've done that with our other sites but was hoping I wouldn't ahve to resort to that within tumblr. Oh well, I guess the answer is no then :) Thanks for clarifying.